# Calculated KPI in Dashboard Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dashboard, performancepoint, kpi

I have two KPIs in the ScoreCard in Sharepoint Dashboard
Now I want to include an additional row between these KPIs in the ScoreCard which shows the division of value of these two KPIs...

> Actual..          10
>   "New column"      {Actual/Target} i.e. 10/12
>   Target..          12

I am sure how to implement this

It will be great if I you give me clue about how to implement this or any link regarding the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually creating an additional Target, with a new name (New Column).  In your case, you want to show the Actual as a percentage of the target.  You can simply set your displayed value to be a percentage and set your indicator thresholds to their particular range and you should be good to go.

I will be happy to provide more detailed directions if needed.

Comment: Thanks Nathan,The name of the KPIs in my example are confusing (sorry for that) But basically what I wanted is a way to compare two KPIs Not sure how to do this but eventually I ended up on comparison on the Measures used in those KPIs It working for me now But i am still if I could compare two KPIs in a scorecard

Comment: The best way to do it is by going directly to the measures, as you have found.